# How do you mark (and measure) the intersection of two lines without adding vertices?

Tags: drivers, measurement, splines, hook-modifier

My issue is that I would like to mark and measure the intersection of two lines so that I can run a driver off the resulting measurement. I thought of adding a vertex, however this will cause the line to bend as it will need to be hooked to the intersecting line. I need to be able to move the two lines independently, maintaining their straightness, but measure where they intersect.  Any ideas on how this might be done? Thank you very much for your help!!
[image]